# How to tell if performance gain for a model is statistically significant?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, cart

I am trying different tree models (different number of features) and getting the following result:

[image]

I can identify the best model (red circle, Approach 1), but I would like to get the most parsimonious model providing results statistically insignificant from the best one.

What kind of test can I apply to check if a performance gain between 2 models was an insignificant one?

(I would like to avoid running cross-validation and comparing means with standard errors if possible).

Comment: The method you apply is probably going to depend on the models you fit - more context would be useful here. For example, with linear regression I can use the extra sum of squares principle/F tests to decide is a feature is important or not. If fitting a hidden markov model with different numbers of hidden states I might just choose the model with largest AIC or BIC which doesn't test for "significance" at all

Comment: In addition to what @jcken has mentioned, you may consider a randomization test (which is a variation of bootstrap). It is relatively slow but it always works. Does not require distributional assumptions.

Comment: @jcken These are boosted trees, if it matters. BIC, AIC and adjusted ² are out of question.

Comment: @stans I would like to avoid any repetitions of model fit/predict and try to rely on the data series available from consecutive single fit/predict if possible

Comment: You will have to engage in at least a few repetitions. A relatively economical approach for comparing two ensembles is cross-validation (say, 5 folds). That is what I use when working with boosted trees and random forests. In that case, however, there is no talk of "significance". To make any decisions on statistical significance, you need to run a formal test. And I do not see how in your (non-parametric) case this can be done without intensive simulations... Most researchers are content with cross-validated improvement. You can also look at out-of-bag (OOB) predictive errors.

Comment: @stans I perfectly getting your point about achieving what I want via CV. My question however is it possible to achieve the same just looking at the sequence of models' metric. And I do have a large number of them.

Comment: **Why** "would [you] like to avoid running cross-validation"?

Comment: @Tim It's already time consuming, several hours. And I'm asking if another opportunity exists.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov you can split the data to train/dev/test once, than there is no re-running the training. If you want to look only on the train set performance you are close to nothing to check for overfitting.

Comment: @Tim How a CV can be done without re-training?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov you train the model on train set, and validate on test set, you don't need to re-train anywhere in here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118786/discussion-between-sergey-bushmanov-and-tim).